# Express : detect 404 errors when using multi-files route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am kind of new on express and I struggle with 404 error detection.

I have a main file called `app.js`, launching the server and specifying files to handle the different requests. As an example :

```
const app = express();

app.use('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), userRoutes);
app.use('/feedback', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), feedbackRoutes);

// Handling errors
app.use(errorController.handle);
```

Then, my `userRoutes` file contains :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const UsersController = require('./controllers/UsersController');

router.get('/list', UsersController.listUsers);
```

So as I have many routes, this worked for me so far and allow a great separation of code. But now I have a problem with 404 detection, because when trying to access a route that doesn't exist such as `/test/foo`, I get the generic express error which is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /test/foo </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I change that do make a proper error management returning a json with the correct http code in the header ? I have put a log at the very beggining of my `errorController.handle` function but it seems we don't even get there.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this in your app.js

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND')
})
```

Comment: It would means I have to make one of these for each HTTP method then ?

Comment: that HTTP method trigerd when you hit enpoint its doesnt exist

Comment: yea but the use of "app.get" means if I make a 404 error with a post request you don't get into that function. So my question was I have to copy - paste these line for each HTTP method to handle all 404 errors

Comment: you dont need to copy - paste that line for each HTTP method , you just need to put on , app.js , yeah it will work for get only , not for post method , if you want to use for post you must add 1 more for post method in app.js